# Issue on Dealing with True False Getting back from Sever Using Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have PHP file which at the end of sending email file I have two echo out as true or false

```
if(@mail($to_Email,$subject,$message,$headers))
{
  echo "true";
}else{
  echo "false";
}
```

I would like to display two alert box in case of success email sending or failure in `#form-messages` so In my JavaScript I have

```
 reqContact.done(function(data) { 
        if(data==true){
           $("#form-messages").html('<div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible" role="alert"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>  <strong>Congrat!</strong> You Sent The Email</div>');
          } 
      else{
           $("#form-messages").html('<div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible" role="alert"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>  <strong>Warning!</strong> You Didnt Send The Email/div>');
        }
  });
```

I am able to send the email but not success to load alert box into `#form-messages`. can you please let me know what i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty sure you are returning a string not boolean.

Try...

```
if(data=="true")
```

Comment: Thanks joe but can you please let me know how come `if(data==="true")` didn't work which I already tried?

Comment: Triple equal signs is the "identical comparison operator". PHP docs say, "TRUE if $a is equal to $b, and they are of the same type.". My guess is it fails the "of the same type" part of the comparison. http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

Comment: if data also contain string as result it should be work with === . but why you use === it strictly check for string if not necessary go with == @suffi